# CartThrob checkout with cart_total = 0,00

Tags: cartthrob, redirects

In certain cases customer check out with a {cart_total} <= 0,00. This happens eg. if a customers redeems a coupon code worth, lets say € 20,00 but in his cart there is only an item worth € 10,00 (shipping neclected for ease of understanding).

Whenever this happens I'd like the customer to overjump the page where he would have to decide on which payment method to choose.

This is my basic flow: Cart > Adress > Payment method > Confirmation with purchase Button.

Now, when a customer is on the Adress page and the cart_total <= 0,00 they should be redirected to the Confirmation page directly.

How would I go about this? I have tried using if conditionals in the {exp:cartthrob:save_customer_info_form} tag but it won't work (parsing issue I guess).

Something like this:

```
{exp:cartthrob:save_customer_info_form
     {if {cart_total} > 0,00}
          return="cart/payment"
     {if:else}
          return="cart/confirmation"
     {/if}
class="validate" secure_action="yes" secure_return="yes"}
```

Thanks for any ideas! Cheers

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you for posting your findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright folks, I've got this figured out. For the sake of a better answered quota I am answering my own question.

This is how ended up doing it:

```
{if '{exp:cartthrob:cart_total prefix=""}' > 0}
     {stash:embed name="snippets:adress-form-a" process="start"}
{if:else}
     {stash:embed name="snippets:adress-form-b" process="start"}
{/if}
```

In the stash embeds there are two different {exp:cartthrob:save_customer_info_form} with different redirects. Case solved.